# SDL2 - Check if OpenGL context is created

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, sdl-2, openglcontext

I am creating an application using SDL2 & OpenGL, and it worked fine on 3 different computers. But on another computer (an updated arch linux), it doesn't, and it crashes with this error:

```
OpenGL context already created
```

So my question is: How do I check if the OpenGL context has already been created? And then, if it is already created, how do I get a handle for it?

If I can't do this, how do I bypass this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SDL2 does **not** in fact create an OpenGL context without you asking to make one. However, if you ask it to create an OpenGL context when OpenGL doesn't work at all, SDL2 likes to, *erm*, freestyle a bit. (The actual reason is that it does a bad job in error checking, so if X fails to create an OpenGL context, it assumes that it's because a context was already created)

So, to answer the third question ("how do I bypass this issue"), you have to fix OpenGL before attempting to use it. Figures, right?

To answer the first and second, well, no API call that I know of... but you can do it a slightly different way:

```
SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_GLContext* context = NULL; // NOTE: This is a pointer!

...

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Stuff here, initialize 'window'

    *context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    // More stuff here

    if (context) {
        // context is initialized!! yay!
    }

    return 2; // Just to confuse people a bit =P
}
```