# When (if ever) will SDL2 reset the rendering context created by SDL_CreateRenderer?

Tags: sdl-2

I'm not using OpenGL in SDL2 directly, but rather I'm creating (what I presume is) a render context by calling `SDL_CreateRenderer`. Should I anticipate SDL2 resetting this rendering context on me at either expected or unexpected times? If so, how do I know when the reset took place? If a reset took place, do I have to reconfigure the context and manually re-load all the buffers with texture data, et. al?

I'm hoping I don't have to do any of this stuff - but I am expecting I probably will... :(

Cheers!

Comment: So you're not using OpenGL at all? Just SDL2? If so, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Awesome! However, would you mind sharing the source of your information?

Comment: After a little searching, I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530720/sdl2-check-if-opengl-context-is-created
Turns out, SDL2 doesn't create an OpenGL context unless you specifically ask it to. But my point still stands ; if you're not telling SDL2 to create a context, it won't create any.